# Digitizing Toolbar greyed out now in QGIS 3.26.2

Tags: layers, editing, digitizing, toolbar

[image]

Since we upgraded QGIS from version 3.16 to 3.26.2 the Digitizing Toolbar is greyed out. I have tried to find the setting that is different between version to unlock it but I can't find it. I need it to edit my Assetfinda Plugin.
How do I unlock it?

Comment: you need to select a layer to be edited

Comment: Hi, sorry it doesn't show on the photo but when I do it is still greyed out. Nothing has changed with my layers or the file I'm using so I'm thinking its a setting in the new version...

Comment: it's working fine for me so I doubt that - could it be permissions?

Comment: We are also thinking that but would you know where? Even our IT aren't sure or not wanting to help me. Would it be to do with the file I'm using? Even though its the same one as I used on the older version or actually within GIS?

Comment: what sort of layer are you using? can you edit it in a project on it's own? with a new profile?

Comment: We have sorted it out. IT found more versions to upgrade and a new plug in from the other program I am using. Thank you